# Undefined variable: products (View: E:\Laravel Projects\laravelstore\resources\views\pages\productsdash.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**I have a problem with the products View**

**Code is in productsdash.blade.php**

```
@if (count($products) > 0)
         @foreach ($products as $product)
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->price}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->condition}}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
      @else
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          No Products Found
        </div>
      @endif
```

**controller index Method**

```
public function index()
    {

        $products=Product::all();
           return view('pages.productsdash',compact('products'));

    }
```

**controller Store Method**

```
public function store(Request $request){


        $product=new Product();
        $product->name=$request->input('name');
        $product->category=$request->input('category');
        $product->condition=$request->input('condition');
        $product->price=$request->input('price');
        $product->platform=$request->input('platform');
        $product->description=$request->input('description');
        $product->save();
        return redirect('/Products')->with('success','Product Added');

    }
```

I don't know what is a problem with my problem.

Comment: Is that the only instance of `view('pages.productsdash')`? I think it's likely you're returning that view elsewhere and not including `products`.

Comment: Could you provide dd($products) here?

Comment: nothing changed i have another project and followed same steps but this project i  can't find the problem

Comment: data on my database stored but i need to show it after added

Comment: can you try do write this in your view on top {{dd($__data);}}, this should dump the data you have passed to your view, and let us see what's passed there

Comment: you should also provide your routes file

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
public function store(Request $request){
        //...
        $product->save();
        $products=Product::all();
        return redirect('/products')->with('success','Product Added')->with('products', $products);
        // OR 
        // you may redirect via named route like : return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('success','Product Added');
        // Named routes allow the convenient generation of URLs or redirects for specific routes. You may specify a name for a route by chaining the name method onto the route definition:

        // Route::get('products', 'Controller@method')->name('products.index');
        // see [redirecting to named route][1] 

}

@forelse ($products as $product)
   <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->price}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->condition}}</td>
   </tr>
@empty
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          No Products Found
    </div>
@endforelse
```

Comment: ndefined variable: products (View: E:\Laravel Projects\laravelstore\resources\views\pages\productsdash.blade.php)

Comment: still same issue

Comment: all of data already stored in my database but i need to show it in a view after added

Comment: Use return redirect('/products')->with('success','Product Added')->with('products', $products);